# How to access variable using string from other scope?

Tags: python, scope

I want to access to variable using string from one file to class in other file.

Here's my code.

File `a.py`:

```
aa = 12
m = test('aa')
```

File `class.py`:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,string):
        try:
            self.variable = globals()[string]
        except KeyError:
            print('there is no variable named ' + string)
```

Above `test.py` code returns sequence string 'there is no variable named blrblr'. I think if Python has lexical scope, the scope when `test()` class first is called should have same scope with `'aa'`, but it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: In what `globals` do you think `class.py` will search? This is why you'll basically never see things like `globals()` (or `locals()`, etc.) in production code. You almost certainly have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The lexical scope of `class test` is `class.py`, not `a.py` so it won't see the variables in  `a.py`.

Comment: Off-topic: One would probably never want to name a module to be imported `class.py` because you wouldn't be able to do `import class` since "class" is a Python keyword.

Comment: `class test` won't have visibility to `a.py` unless it imports that module. You could do `m = test(globals()['aa'])` in `a.py` if you want to resolve the variable dynamically. Otherwise, you need to pass the module to `test` - or the name of the module and let `test` import it dynamically.

Comment: Well, I misunderstood definition of lexical scope. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`globals()` returns a dictionary of attributes for the **current module**. The usual way to access code in a different file is with `import`. For example

```
import a
```

Now you can access variables from `a.py` directly in code:

```
print(a.aa)
```

While there are ways to do it, it is not advisable to try to use a string as a variable name. Instead, you should use a data structure such as a dictionary.